# Error clipping raster files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, extract-by-mask

I have a series of raster files I´d like to clip to the same extent. To do so I am using a shapefile as mask through the method (raster >extraction> clipper) but every time I do so I keep getting the same error "cutline feature without geometry".

I have tried many suggestions in this site. Amongst the most common; I have validated my shapes geometry and it seems to have no errors, the files are in the same projection, and the polygon I am using as a mask to clip my raster files is smaller than the extent of these.

I know it´s a very common topic but I am running out of options and I am there might be a problem either with my raster files or my shapefile which I am obviously overlooking.

I leave the link to the zip files below.

[Zip files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m10uwREC9kQR_1BF2FF3g8847IEDEloj)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a problem with your polygon layer rather than the tool itself. Using the files you supplied, I encounter the same issue. There appears to be one feature, but multiple entries in the table. Running a number of different tools, the processing log often spits out `Feature n has invalid geometry. Skipping...`

I can't make sense of what's wrong with this layer.

**Solution:**

Rather than dig into the details of the layer itself, I just ran **Fixed distance buffer** with a Distance of 0. Using this new vector layer as your mask layer should work just fine.

**Updated Solution:**

I revisited this out of curiosity, and those empty features were the problem. As the features have no actual geometry to them, they're the reason you get the "...without a geometry" error message.

Selecting by expression `$area IS NULL` and then deleting left the table with one feature, the polygon we're masking with. The raster was then able to be clipped using the original shapefile.

[image: output]

Comment: Correct! The problem was with my polygon. I tried what you suggested and it ran swiftly, also tried creating my polygon from another raster file and it ran without problem. I still don´t understand what was the problem, but it is working now. Thanks a lot, it was great help!